# Set Product Version and File Version On A .def file Created With Kotlin MPP MinGW

Tags: dll, mingw, mingw-w64, kotlin-multiplatform

I tried adding the version when converting the .def generated by MinGW into a DLL using this
`lib.exe /MACHINE:X64 /def:.\build\bin\windows\releaseShared\libMyLib.def /out:.\build\bin\windows\releaseShared\libMyLib.lib /VERSION:$env:MY_VERSION`
But the resulting dll still have 1.0.0.0 as versions

Anyone can help? How can I insert the version info in the .def?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what end up working for me:

in my build.gradle

```
fun org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.SharedLibrary.windowsResources(rcFileName: String) {
    val taskName = linkTaskName.replaceFirst("link", "windres")
    val inFile = compilation.defaultSourceSet.resources.sourceDirectories.singleFile.resolve(rcFileName)
    val outFile = buildDir.resolve("processedResources/$taskName.res")

    val windresTask = tasks.create<Exec>(taskName) {
        val konanUserDir = System.getenv("KONAN_DATA_DIR") ?: "${System.getProperty("user.home")}/.konan"
        val konanLlvmDir = "$konanUserDir/dependencies/msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin"

        inputs.file(inFile)
        outputs.file(outFile)
        commandLine("$konanLlvmDir/windres", inFile, "-D_${buildType.name}", "-v", "-O", "coff", "-o", outFile)
        environment("PATH", "$konanLlvmDir;${System.getenv("PATH")}")

        dependsOn(compilation.compileKotlinTask)
    }

    linkTask.dependsOn(windresTask)
    linkerOpts(outFile.toString())
}
```

where `msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1` is my current version of mingw.

And still in the build.gradle:

```
kotlin {
    mingwX64("windows") {
        binaries {
            sharedLib {
                windowsResources("version.rc")
                baseName = "libMyLib"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and version.rc the name of my resources file in the folder src/windowsMain/resources